# translate python code to javascript

Tags: javascript, utf-8, char, numbers

I need help to translate this python code to an other language. I would like to convert this python code to javascript:

Original code (python) :

```
data = list("\x01\x03\x19 @ \x06\x01\x03\x01\x02\x01\x03\x01\x03\x18\x01\x03\x01\x03\x07\x01\x03\x01\x03\x01\x02\x01\x03\x01\x03\x01\x02\x01\x03\x0eAdministrateur \x01\x03\x01\x03\x01\x03\x01\x03\x17\xb4G\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x01\x03\x80\x01\x03 \x01\x03\x08\x04\x86N\x84\x8a\n\x90\x90\x90t\x8e\x80\x01\x03\x01\x02\x01\x03\x01\x03\x01\x02\x01\x03\x04#\xb90\xb22\x99\x18\x18\x10\x01\x03\x01\x03\x01\x03\x01\x03\x0b\xdaC\x0c5\x08:\x98\x01\x03\xc0\x01\x030\x01\x03\x0c\x01\x03C'BE\x05HHH:G\x01\x03\x00")
result = ""
for id, char in enumerate(data):
   result+= ord(char)+" "

// output
// "1 3 25 32 64 32 6 1 3 1 2 1 3 1 3 24 1 3 1 3 7 1 3 1 3 1 2 1 3 1 3 1 2 1 3 14 65 100 109 105 110 105 115 116 114 97 116 101 117 114 32 1 3 1 3 1 3 1 3 23 180 71 255 255 255 255 255 1 3 128 1 3 32 1 3 8 4 134 78 132 138 10 144 144 144 116 142 128 1 3 1 2 1 3 1 3 1 2 1 3 4 35 185 48 178 50 153 24 24 16 1 3 1 3 1 3 1 3 11 218 67 12 53 8 58 152 1 3 192 1 3 48 1 3 12 1 3 67 39 66 69 5 72 72 72 58 71 1 3 0 "
// notice at the beggin -> "1 3 25 32 64"
```

I tried (Javascript) :

```js
var data = "\x01\x03\x19 @ \x06\x01\x03\x01\x02\x01\x03\x01\x03\x18\x01\x03\x01\x03\x07\x01\x03\x01\x03\x01\x02\x01\x03\x01\x03\x01\x02\x01\x03\x0eAdministrateur \x01\x03\x01\x03\x01\x03\x01\x03\x17\xb4G\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x01\x03\x80\x01\x03 \x01\x03\x08\x04\x86N\x84\x8a\n\x90\x90\x90t\x8e\x80\x01\x03\x01\x02\x01\x03\x01\x03\x01\x02\x01\x03\x04#\xb90\xb22\x99\x18\x18\x10\x01\x03\x01\x03\x01\x03\x01\x03\x0b\xdaC\x0c5\x08:\x98\x01\x03\xc0\x01\x030\x01\x03\x0c\x01\x03C'BE\x05HHH:G\x01\x03\x00"
data = data.replace("\x02", "");
data = data.replace("\x03", "");
data = data.split('')
var result = "";
data.forEach(function(char, id) {
  result += char.charCodeAt(0) + " ";
});
console.log(result);
```

```
// output 
// "1 25 32 64 32 6 1 3 1 1 3 1 3 24 1 3 1 3 7 1 3 1 3 1 2 1 3 1 3 1 2 1 3 14 65 100 109 105 110 105 115 116 114 97 116 101 117 114 32 1 3 1 3 1 3 1 3 23 180 71 255 255 255 255 255 1 3 128 1 3 32 1 3 8 4 134 78 132 138 10 144 144 144 116 142 128 1 3 1 2 1 3 1 3 1 2 1 3 4 35 185 48 178 50 153 24 24 16 1 3 1 3 1 3 1 3 11 218 67 12 53 8 58 152 1 3 192 1 3 48 1 3 12 1 3 67 39 66 69 5 72 72 72 58 71 1 3 0 "
// notice et the begin -> "1 25 32 64"
```

Thank to help me.

Comment: You're removing `\x02` and `\x03` in Javascript, but the Python script doesn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

What for did you use replace???

```js
var data = "\x01\x03\x19 @ \x06\x01\x03\x01\x02\x01\x03\x01\x03\x18\x01\x03\x01\x03\x07\x01\x03\x01\x03\x01\x02\x01\x03\x01\x03\x01\x02\x01\x03\x0eAdministrateur \x01\x03\x01\x03\x01\x03\x01\x03\x17\xb4G\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x01\x03\x80\x01\x03 \x01\x03\x08\x04\x86N\x84\x8a\n\x90\x90\x90t\x8e\x80\x01\x03\x01\x02\x01\x03\x01\x03\x01\x02\x01\x03\x04#\xb90\xb22\x99\x18\x18\x10\x01\x03\x01\x03\x01\x03\x01\x03\x0b\xdaC\x0c5\x08:\x98\x01\x03\xc0\x01\x030\x01\x03\x0c\x01\x03C'BE\x05HHH:G\x01\x03\x00"
data = data.split('')
var result = "";
data.forEach(function(char, id) {
  result += char.charCodeAt(0) + " ";
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to be correct but I don't know what you were wanting it to do.  Did you expect the second sequence to be 3?

You removed all of the \x03 with this statement:

```
data = data.replace("\x03", "");
```

So the second sequence is now \x19 which converts to dec 25.

If you remove the two replace statements, the outputs should match.